# optidef existence problem

Tags: optidef

Is there a way to replace "minimize" and "maximize" in `optidef` package with something that will display "exists"? I am wondering how to best typeset an existence problem in `optidef`, though maybe that's not the right package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what your intended input or output is. However, as a guess the following approach: you can use the `customopti` environment with the problem keyword as first (mandatory) argument.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{customopti}
{exists}{w}{f(w)+ R(w+6x)}
{\label{eq:Example1}}{}
\addConstraint{g(w)}{=0}
\addConstraint{n(w)}{= 6}
\addConstraint{L(w)+r(x)}{=Kw+p}
\addConstraint{h(x)}{=0.}
\end{customopti}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this requires the latest version from Github (https://github.com/jeslago/optidef/blob/master/optidef.sty), which is currently (June 2021) not yet on CTAN.

Comment: I'd be wary of using `\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{exists}`, because it silently overwrites the existing command `\exists`.

Comment: @egreg good point, I changed the environment name.

Comment: @Marijn @egreg: Perhaps this could also be done using the `customopti` environment in `optidef` (see line 795 of https://github.com/jeslago/optidef/blob/master/optidef.sty) though it doesnt seem to be documented and when I tried it, it didn't seem to work for me

Comment: @rrrrr that is much easier indeed :) my installed version of the package didn't have this environment yet. I edited the answer. The centering of _subject to_ is also better in this version.